# How do you create a table to look at the most recent GCS Bucket File?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to figure out a way to create a table/view within a dataset to look at a specific GCS Bucket and look at the most recent file as files would be uploaded daily into the GCS Bucket folder.

Is this possible to do with a wild card or what is the best way to do this? Is there any documentation to look at to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Maykid

Comment: Might this be a useful reference to what you are looking for?

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/hive-partitioned-queries-gcs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a cloud function trigger as soon as the file is added to cloud storage, cloud function will export  its data to bigquery dataset in a new table or existing one based on the requirement, Another way is use cloud composer with cloud storage trigged event